# PrimeNG using dock click shows context menu

Tags: node.js, angular, primeng

Im using angular2 installed with npm primeNG

My question is how to use the dock icon double click and show the context menu as desired.
As illustrated in below picture.
[image]

Any help or advise will be really appreciated.
Thanks